# Usage of SearchBuilder in NEST ElasticSearch client

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I was wondering if anyone had any tips or examples for using the SearchBuilder API in NEST. The docs are still kinda sparse.

I am looking to dynamically construct queries/filters based on criteria sent in URL parameters. An example:

www.mydomain.com/things/search?prop1=3&prop2=foo&prop3=bar

And once I extract those I want to build an exact-match query based on the criteria that are present.

Answer (score 3):

Using the DSL query syntax you can now simply do this:

```
var results = client.Search(s=>s
    .Fields(new string[0])
    .Query(q=>
        q.Term(ESFields.City, city)
        && q.Term(ESFields.State, state)
    )
);
```

Which relies on the `conditionless query` support added in 0.9.10.0.

This will only render the city query if `city` holds a value and only the state term query if `state` is not null or empty.

- If both are valid it will do a bool query
- If only one is valid it will do just the one term query
- If neither is valid it will fall back to a match_all query.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
  var boolQuery = QueryFactory.BoolQuery();
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(city)) { boolQuery.Must(QueryFactory.TermQuery(ESFields.City, city)); }
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state)) { boolQuery.Must(QueryFactory.TermQuery(ESFields.State, state)); }
  //etc. for many fields

  var sb = SearchBuilder.Builder();
  //I want no actual data - this will ensure I only get IDs
  sb.Fields(new string[0]);
  sb.Query(boolQuery);

  var companyIds = ((ElasticClient)_elasticClient).Search(sb, ESIndexes.Client, ESIndexTypes.Client, tenantId)
    .DocumentsWithMetaData.Select(d => d.Id).ToList();
```

Not sure this is the most efficient/effective way to do it, but it works.